# How to handle void decltype();

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I'd like to create a template that calls a member function on another object that returns the same type as the member function.  The syntax for using decltype on the member function is a bit ugly, but it seems to work in every case except one.

Here's the call:

```
struct container: map<string, C> 
{
    template< typename MemFnPtrType, typename... _ArgTypes>
    auto safeOperation(string key, MemFnPtrType mfp, _ArgTypes&&... args )
        -> decltype( (((C*)nullptr)->*mfp)(args...))
    {
        C* pC = NULL;
        decltype((pC->*mfp)(args...)) result;

        iterator it = find(key);
        if (it != end())
        {
            C* pC = &(it->second);
            result = (pC->*mfp)(args...);
            cout << "result:" << result << "\n";
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "key: " << key << " missing\n";
        }
        return result;
    }
};
```

This works fine until the member function returns void.

Is there a way to detect this and leave out the offending lines?

I could obviously create a voidSafeOperation function.  I don't mind creating another template, but I'd like to use the same name "safeOperation" so the call sites don't need to use different helpers based on the return type of the member function.

Thanks!

Full Example: 
http://cpp.sh/7ft

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately, I think you're stuck here with having to SFINAE on the return type. Start with a type trait (this is *way* cleaner than your `decltype` expression)

```
template <typename MF, typename... Args>
using Res = typename std::result_of<MF(C, Args...)>::type;
```

And then just switch:

```
template <typename MF, typename... Args>
typename std::enable_if<
    std::is_same<Res<MF, Args...>, void>::value
>::type safeOperation(string key, MF mfp, Args... args)
{
     /* void case */
}

template <typename MF, typename... Args>
typename std::enable_if<
    !std::is_same<Res<MF, Args...>, void>::value,
    Res<MF, Args...>
>::type safeOperation(string key, MF mfp, Args... args)
{
     /* non-void case */
}
```

Or you could tag dispatch on `is_void`:

```
template <typename MF, typename... Args>
Res<MF, Args...> safeOperation(string key, MF mfp, Args... args)
{
    return safeOperation(std::is_void<Res<MF, Args...>>{},
                         key, mfp, args...);
}
```

with:

```
template <typename MF, typename... Args>
void safeOperation(std::true_type /* void */, 
                   string key, MF mfp, Args... args) 
{ .. }

template <typename MF, typename... Args>
Res<MF, Args...> safeOperation(std::false_type /* non-void */, 
                               string key, MF mfp, Args... args) 
{ .. }
```

Comment: Or tag dispatch on `is_void`.

Comment: @T.C. I'm usually not a huge fan, but in this case it's very clean.

Comment: I was able to compile the first case, but the syntax for the result in the !void case using is_void dispatch seems to be eluding me:
http://cpp.sh/7mep

Comment: @BitBlitz Woops! Fixed.

Comment: Perfect, thanks!

Working example for those who come later: http://cpp.sh/6aav

Turns out when I tried to put this in my build environment the GCC (4.6)  is too old, but supports the ugly decltype() - 
Still I was able to solve the void problem with an is_void tag.  Not beautiful but saves me a ton of work. 

Thanks again!

Comment: What's wrong with just `std::is_void<Res<MF, Args...>>{}` and skipping `typename ::type`?

Comment: @T.C. Nothing in particular.

Answer (score 1):

It is a corner case. `auto` with `decltype` for trailing return type don't work for a `void` return type because `void` is an incomplete type.

example:

```
auto nothingMuch()
{
    return;
}

// nope
//decltype(void {}) nothingMuchEither()
//{
//  return;
//}

// nope
//auto noTrailing() -> decltype(void {})
//{
//
//}

// always works
decltype(auto) nothing()
{
    return;
}

auto main() -> decltype(int {})
{
    nothing();
    nothingMuch();
    return 0;
}
```

The easiest fix is to replace `auto` and `decltype` in the trailing return type with `decltype(auto)` as the return type (needs C++14).